# Tableview won't reload after contacts permission granted

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, contacts

I am using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.2.1.

I need help reloading a tableview after the Contacts permission request appears and is granted.  Currently, the dialogue box shows requesting permission on first use, but after it is granted during that first use, the tableview will not reload.  If I close the app and reopen, the contacts show as intended (in other words, it shows fine when the request permission dialogue does not show).  Here is my code:

In `viewDidLoad` of the `ContactsViewController`:

```
    // Load the contacts from the phone
    ContactService.fetchContacts(completion: { (contacts) in
        if contacts != nil {
            self.deviceContacts = contacts!
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
    })
```

In `ContactService`:

```
static func fetchContacts(completion: @escaping (_ contacts: [Contact]?) -> Void) {

    var deviceContacts:[Contact] = [Contact]()

    // Set up default storage for the contacts
    let store = CNContactStore()

    // Request access to the contacts if not already given.
    store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, error) in

        if let error = error {

            print("Failed to request access:", error)
            completion (nil)
        }

        if granted {
            print("Access granted.")

            // Information to retrieve
            let keys = [CNContactIdentifierKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactNicknameKey, CNContactNameSuffixKey, CNContactOrganizationNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactImageDataAvailableKey, CNContactImageDataKey]

            let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])

            // Sort by last name
            request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.familyName

            do {

                try store.enumerateContacts(with: request
                    , usingBlock: { (contact, stopPointerifYouWantToStopEnumerating) in

                        // Got the contacts from the device, now format as a Contact and put them into our array
                        let formattedContact = Contact(contactDetails: contact, favoriteNumbers: [], opened: false)
                        deviceContacts.append(formattedContact)
                })

            } catch let error {
                print("Failed to enumerate contacts:", error)
            }
        } else {
            print ("Access denied.")
            completion (nil)
        }
    }
        completion(deviceContacts)
}
```

I tried putting a `dispatchGroup.enter()` and `.leave()` inside `if granted` and `.notify` in the completion in `fetchContacts` but it did not work.

Comment: Move `completion(deviceContacts)` inside the `store.requestAccess` completion block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change place of `completion`

```
try store.enumerateContacts(with: request
    , usingBlock: { (contact, stopPointerifYouWantToStopEnumerating) in

        // Got the contacts from the device, now format as a Contact and put them into our array
        let formattedContact = Contact(contactDetails: contact, favoriteNumbers: [], opened: false)
        deviceContacts.append(formattedContact)
})  
completion(deviceContacts)
```

Currently it's out of `store.requestAccess(for: .contacts) { (granted, error) in`
 that supposed to retrieve the contacts  , also you don't need a dispatch group here as it's 1 single asynchronous task not many

---

Result of `requestAccess` occurs in a background thread , so consider

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
  self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: It is partially working now.  After I grant permission, the tableview is still blank.  But if I go to another VC and come back, the contacts are there.  Previously, going and coming back would not show them.  How can I show them without leaving and returning?

Comment: can you add a break point in `   self.tableView.reloadData()` to see it triggers or not after accept permission ? also where you set the delegate and dataSource limes

Comment: There is a purple ! that says UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only.  Should I move it outside the `if` statement?  Delegates are set in viewDidLoad below the fetchContacts line.

Comment: make then above `fetchContacts` and wrap the reload inside the main queue see above